# How do I un/marshall attributed elements in JAXB?

Tags: scala, jaxb, moxy

It seems like this should be fairly obvious, but I can't find anything on how to simply (un)marshall XML elements which also have attributes using JAXB.

In other words, I understand how to use JAXB annotations to work with:

```
<element>foo</element>
```

And I understand how to use JAXB with:

```
<element attribute1="bar" attribute2="foo" />
```

But I can't figure out how to approach something like:

```
<id_address href="/addresses/18">18></id_address_delivery>
<id_cart href="/carts/111">111</id_cart>
<id_currency href="/currencies/13">13></id_currency>
```

It feels like I should be able to do something like this (I'm using JAXB from Scala):

```
@XmlElement
@BeanProperty
var idAddress: XLink = _

@XmlElement
@BeanProperty
var idCart: XLink = _

@XmlElement
@BeanProperty
var idCurrency: XLink = _
```

And then define `XLink` as:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class XLink {

  @XmlAttribute
  @BeanProperty
  var href: String = _

  @Xml???
  @BeanProperty // ID is the container
  var id: Long = _
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work, because `id` shouldn't be a sub-element  - it's simply the value of the parent node.

This is such a common use case: what am I missing? For completeness, I'm using JAXB (MOXy) from Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `@XmlValue`.

See [here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/jaxb-annotations.xtp#XmlValue) for more info.

Comment: Big thanks James - this works great. Sorry for the delay in testing it!